# Sending variables to php from objective C Cocoa

Tags: php, string, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I am trying to pass a variable to a php page, but it's not being passed to the page or being saved in the database.  See the comments in the following code:

```
NSString *fname=@"fname";
NSString *lname=@"lname";
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Test-objective%20c%20/send.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@",fname,lname];

NSLog(urlString);

NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSAlert *dq= [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[dq setMessageText:urlString];
[dq runModal];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];

NSAlert *d= [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[d setMessageText:@"connection"];
[d runModal];

//This is the part I don't understand.
//This line has a problem:  
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Test-objectivec/send.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@",fname,lname];

//But when I replace it with
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8888/Test-objectivec/send.php?first_name=My&last_name=nme";

//Then it works just fine.
```

Also, can anybody tell me how to see the response from server?

Comment: Change the log to `NSLog(@"URL string: %@", urlString);`. Debug, is everything created?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *fname=@"fname";
NSString *lname=@"lname";
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]  

NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Test-objectivec/send.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@",fnamelname];
```

- Remove white space from  "Test-objective c " which converted %20 this is creating problem.

Comment: %20 treated as special in objective c

Comment: i have removed spaces but variables are not inserted in database. whats the problem when i give value via variables otherwise via static first_name and last_name as i explained in my question before it works fine .

Comment: SO ADD %% IN PLACE OF %

Comment: the code is working fine now when i used NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8888/Test-objectivec/send.php?first_name=My&last_name=nme"; but when used NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Test-objectivec/send.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@",fnamelname];
its don't insert.

Comment: i have add the //THis is the thing which i don't understand in question, the main problem i don't understand.

Comment: I think php server doesn't use any port with localhost use only http://localhost/Test-objectivec

Answer (score 0):

When you create a string with a format you need to be careful of special characters in the format. Particularly in your case `%`. The format should be:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Test-objective%%20c%%20/send.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@",fname,lname];
```

Comment: the code is working fine now when i used NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8888/Test-objectivec/send.php?first_name=My&last_name=nme"; but when used NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/Test-objectivec/send.php?first_name=%@&last_name=%@",fnamelname];.it not worked.

Comment: The links in your comment aren't valid. Add code updates to the bottom of your question (and check the formatting).

Comment: i have add the "THis is the thing which i don't understand" in  my question the main problem i don't understand